# Sourcetree: Invalid password for Github despite having a valid OAUTH token on Windows

Tags: windows, git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I use Github and Sourcetree on my Windows machine.

I have been into `Tools - Options - Authentication` and added my Github account. I am 120% sure that my settings are correct.

However, when I try to push anything, I keep getting:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags origin develop:develop
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.

remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'REPOLINK'

Pushing to REPOLINK
Completed with errors, see above.
```

Now, I also tried to remove the account in my settings, and then entering e-mail / password manually. Usually it will say OK and ask for my 2FA code on my phone, but for now it just fails and responds with invalid username/password.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Still a problem. I also tried to decrease my commit size from 15k files to just 1. Doesn't work.

I managed to commit through the console (but I have to fill credentials each time).

So unfortunately this is still unsolved.

Comment: What version of Git are you using?  This error doesn't _sound_ related to the changes that GitHub made, but have you updated it based on https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/

Comment: They're unfortunately updated :-)

Some extra info. I am able to pull the repo no problem, but when I commit, I get the login issue. Worth noticing is I am committing ~15.000 files, which obviously is a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a very good answer, but I still wanted to show my solution now 1.5 months have gone by.

On 3 computers I've failed to get Sourcetree to work. I'm using Windows on all machines, and above problem keeps happening no matter what I do. I've tried preferences/settings, filling it on prompt...

I doubt it's my account - I use Github OAUTH in many other programs.

The day after this post, I switched to SmartGit. Works much better and no problems, and will not go back.

This is a very bad answer - but if you're ending up here from Google - this is one possible solution.

Answer (score 6):

http://www.omniweb.com/wordpress/?p=1291 this person solved it, it works for me.

navigating to C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree and removing (or renaming) the passwd file.

Once this file is removed, restart SourceTree and execute a fetch or something else that requires access to the repo in question. SourceTree will then prompt you for your password, rewriting the cached credentials.

Comment: I'm no sure why you got downvoted, but this worked for me. +1 Thanks